# Sorts even numbers in ascending order and sorts odd numbers in descending order in C language

Tags: c

A function that moves the sorted at the beginning followed by the sorted odd numbers in descending order of an array. (Store it in an array, this array can be accessible at the main program)

Example:

Input: 2 3 4 5 2 1 3
Output: 2 2 4 5 3 3 1

Input: 5 -3 4  2 -11 -4 6
Output: -4 2 4 5 -3 -11

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int sorted_even(int[], int);
int main()
{
    
int i,n;    

printf("Enter how many elements:");
scanf("%d",&n);

int arr[n];
printf("Enter %d elements:\n", n);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    scanf("\n%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    sorted_even(arr,n);
    
}   


int sorted_even(int arr[], int n)
{
int arr1[n], j, k, c=0, temp, b;
int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]%2==1)
        c++;
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
        if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
            {
            temp=arr[j];
            arr[j]=arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    k=0;
    j=n-c;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
    if(arr[i]%2==0)
        {
        if(k<n-c)
        arr1[k++]=arr[i];
        }
    else
        {
        if(j<n)
        arr1[j++]=arr[i];
        }
    }   
    
printf("\nresults:");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    arr[i]=arr1[i];
    printf("\n%d", arr[i]);
    }
    
}
```

But I have some problems when it comes to sorting the Odd numbers in descending order. :'<

Comment: "I have some problems with my code" Is not very helpful. What doesn't work, what exactly do you have problems with?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are doing this as part of some algorithm theory class, you probably shouldn't be inventing your own sorting algorithms. Notably you are using "bubble sort" which is the least efficient one.

If we instead write the code so that we separate the element comparison logic from the sorting algorithm, everything turns much more modular and maintainable. That's how standard C `qsort` works. It could be implemented as a "quick sort" algorithm, or a merge sort, we don't have to know or care how. We just provide the element comparison as a callback function passed to `qsort`, which will then call our function over and over during sorting.

As required by the `qsort` specification, our comparison function should return a number less than 0, equal to zero or larger than zero, depending on if the first object is smaller, equal or larger than the second object.

In your case, it goes like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int even_asc_odd_desc (const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
  const int* i1 = p1;
  const int* i2 = p2;
  
  if(*i1 & 1)
    if(*i2 & 1)  // both odd
      return *i1 < *i2;
    else         // first odd, second even
      return 1;
  else
    if(*i2 & 1)  // first even, second odd
      return -1;
    else         // both even
      return *i2 < *i1;
}

int main(void)
{
  int arr1[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3};     // Output: 2 2 4 5 3 3 1
  int arr2[] = {5, -3, 4, 2, -11, -4, 6}; // Output: -4 2 4 6 5 -3 -11

  qsort(arr1, sizeof arr1/sizeof *arr1, sizeof *arr1, even_asc_odd_desc);
  qsort(arr2, sizeof arr2/sizeof *arr2, sizeof *arr2, even_asc_odd_desc);

  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof arr1/sizeof *arr1; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr1[i]);
  printf("\n");
  
  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof arr2/sizeof *arr2; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr2[i]);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;   
}
```

Now even if you want to write your own sorting algorithm, you can still use a comparison function like above, to separate the sorting from the comparison logic.

Just for reference, this is how you'd implement it with the same generic function template as standard C `qsort`:

```
void bubble_sort (void* base, 
                  size_t nmemb, 
                  size_t size,
                  int (*compar)(const void*, const void*))
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<nmemb-1; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<nmemb-i-1; j++)
    {
      // we can't do pointer arithmetic on void*, convert to integer type:
      uintptr_t o1 = (uintptr_t)base + j*size;
      uintptr_t o2 = (uintptr_t)base + (j+1)*size;

      // then convert back to pointer types:
      void* p1 = (void*)o1;
      void* p2 = (void*)o2;
      
      if( compar(p1, p2) > 0 ) // if *p1 > *p2
      {
        // swap items
        unsigned char tmp[size];
        memcpy(tmp, p1,  size);
        memcpy(p1,  p2,  size);
        memcpy(p2,  tmp, size);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can replace `qsort` with `bubble_sort` in the first example and get the same result - and now we've invented a crappier generic sorting algorithm than the fast standard one already provided to us.

Comment: Your `even_asc_odd_desc` function does not seem to be fully compliant with `qsort`, If `*i1` is 5 and `*i2` is 3, it returns 0 instead of -1. Similarly, if `*i1` is 2 and `*i2` is 4, it returns 0 instead of -1.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yeah probably, I just hacked this down in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

as i understand, you want to sort all the array in `arr` and then reorder them by odd and even in `arr1`, so you have to set the odd numbers with reverse order, start with `n` and then back, `k` and `j` will meet at the middle becase you count the number of odd numbers first.

this code will do the trick:

```
k=0;
j=n-1;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(arr[i]%2==0)
    {
        arr1[k++]=arr[i];
    }
    else
    {
        arr1[j--]=arr[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as required. I initialized the variable j to 0 and inserting the odd elements in the sorted array arr to the back of the new array arr1.

```
k=0;
j=0;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){   
    if(arr[i]%2==0)
    {
        if(k<n-c){
            arr1[k]=arr[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(j<n){
            arr1[n-j-1]=arr[i];
            j++;
        }    
    }
}   

printf("\nresults:\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
//arr[i]=arr1[i];
    printf("%d\n", arr1[i]);
}
```